# IndexOutOfBounds using Javas imageio.write() to create byte array in png format

Tags: java, exception, png, arrays, javax.imageio

I am using `javax.imageio.ImageIO` to write a `BufferedImage b` into a byte array and finally to a file. 1 out of 10 times when creating the byte array, a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. It is not reproducible by just using the same image though.

```
BufferedImage img = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// the next line will lead to the exception being thrown
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray()
```

Result is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Line | Method
->>  166 | seek                       in
javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    227 | close                      in     ''
|   1570 | write . . . . . . . . . .  in javax.imageio.ImageIO
```

I found a [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=dc84943191e06dffffffffdf200f5210dd319?bug_id=6967419), seemingly describing the same problem. But I cannot find a fix though it's from 2010.

Any ideas? Work arounds? Links to ressources?

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the byte array for anything or do you just want to save the BufferedImage to file?

Comment: Hey Dan! Thanks for your interest. I need the byte[] in order to have the image in memory. It is distributed to DBs and streamed to a website.

Comment: I am not sure how you use byte[] byteArray = ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
There are 3 versions of ImageIO.write and they all return a boolean.

Comment: Aye, you're right. That was a c'n'p error when compiling my question. It's in a function that is returning a boolean indeed. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=dc84943191e06dffffffffdf200f5210dd319?bug_id=6967419).
Though, if you read through the report you'll see...

> CUSTOMER SUBMITTED WORKAROUND :
>
> Use a memory cache.

Try to utilize a [`MemoryCacheImageOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.html) instead, until the bug is squashed *eventually*.

```
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(baos));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick!! I have the feeling it became a lot slower - but I can live with that for now (or would you have any hint on that?). Of course I had read the ticket. To be honest, I just wasn't aware that there is a MemoryCacheImageOutputStream class and did not understand what was meant.

Comment: @fluxon the major difference between the two is that using a *file* cache uses a file for storing data before sending it off, while a *memory* cache would just store it in memory instead. Whether or not it's slower is a complex question, though, which is highly context-sensitive.

Comment: The bug has been finally resolved on the 1st of Decembre 2015. The fix will be available with Java 9.